# Where to get Ubuntu for Dell Inspiron 14 5000 Series 5480

Tags: dell, inspiron, preinstallation

[Ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 5480](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201807-26321/) website says to use pre-installed version of OS, but it shipped with Windows 10.

> The system is available in some regions with a special image of Ubuntu pre-installed by the manufacturer. It takes advantage of the hardware features for this system and may include additional software. You should check when buying the system whether this is an option.

However the [Dell website](https://www.dell.com/support/article/my/en/mydhs1/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en) says to download Ubuntu directly from the official Ubuntu website.

Update 21/01/2020

As of this day I am using 19.10 with LXQt (Gnome Lags on this hardware )
Major problem I faced were

```
1) No out of box hibernation
2) Super fast Battey drainage
3) Cant controle bios settings from OS .

Problem 1) I was able to resolve it .
Problem 2) somewhat resolved
Problem 3) still not fixed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought the Inspirion 14 5480 and Ubuntu 18.04 came pre-installed, unfortunately Dell does not have this Ubuntu OEM on its website, I already asked for support for that. They recommend installing Ubuntu from the website. kkkk! But if you download it it will start to heat up with anything, and bad to type. In the Ubuntu OEM that came installed, the FAN spends most of the time 0.

Answer (score 4):

Dell Inspiron 14 5480 may come with Windows OS as you can see on their website: [Inspiron 14 5480 Laptop - Dell India](https://www.dell.com/en-in/shop/laptops-2-in-1-pcs/inspiron-14-5480-laptop/spd/inspiron-14-5480-laptop)

It is quite possible that the same model is being sold with Ubuntu, Windows or DOS. If you want to install Ubuntu then you can download the .iso file from Ubuntu website here: [Download Ubuntu Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

You can choose Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS which has long-term support. You can go for either dual boot or may replace Windows with Ubuntu completely.

New Windows installs are associated with a Microsoft ID and no product key is provided with them. During reinstall they are automatically activated on signing in with the same Microsoft account as used for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

The official Dell website is correct. The Dell Inspiron 14 5000 Series 5480 laptop shipped with Windows preinstalled. For Dell computers that shipped with Windows preinstalled download and install the Ubuntu .iso file from the [official Ubuntu website](https://www.ubuntu.com/download).

[Ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 5480](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201807-26321/) website goes on to say:

> Standard images of Ubuntu may not work at all on the system or may not work well, though Canonical and computer manufacturers will try to certify the system with future standard releases of Ubuntu.

This quote is specific for laptop models that ship with Ubuntu preinstalled. Dell often ships these models with different hardware and pre-installed device drivers that do not have the same compatibility issues as laptop models that do not ship with special Linux-friendly hardware, so the website is recommending that you stick with the device drivers that are already pre-installed on these laptops instead of doing a fresh installation of Ubuntu which may result in suboptimal performance.

The [Dell website](https://www.dell.com/support/article/my/en/mydhs1/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en) goes on to say:

> Be aware Dell does not supply the majority of drivers for Ubuntu as all the required drivers are bundled as part of the Operating System install media. That's why we recommend you check your system is compatible with the install media version from Canonical.

This quote would be equally true for any laptop that does not ship with Ubuntu preinstalled. The thing to do in this case is to make an Ubuntu live DVD/USB and try Ubuntu in a live session without installing it. This will enable you to check if all the hardware devices work on Ubuntu. If not, it's easy to install missing device drivers on the Ubuntu live USB without installing any software on the internal hard disk.

Comment: I forgot to add full name its actually  inspiron 14 5000 Series 5480 , not latitude.